# C# fields not retaining values when stored in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a situation in my program where I have around 20 fields. All of them are strings. Now I also have an array of strings of size 20. I want to sequentially initialize those fields from the string stored inside this array. I do not want to do this:

field1 = array[0];

field2 = array[1];

....

field20 = array[19];

So I wrote a test program like this but it doesn't work with strings. It's only working with reference types. Is there any way to do it?

```
public class Program
{
    private string name;
    private string id;

    private void Func()
    {
        var array = new[] {name, id};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = "some string";
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Func();
        Console.WriteLine(p.name); // prints null
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do that by using reflection but you should not. And in this assigment: `array[i] = "some string";` you are throwing away the old reference, and assigning a new value to `array[i]` so that's why it doesn't change the value of `name`.

Comment: @ user2864740 - ok that's right. can you tell how to assign all the fields for p object with the corressponding string values inside the array?

Comment: Why downvotes? This is correct beginners' question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumptions about the behavior are incorrect.

```
// Create a NEW array with the specified expressions which are evaluated
// immediately (to the current values of the fields)..
var array = new[] {name, id};

// Meaning it is equivalent to this .. note that the field names have
// NOTHING to do with the array object itself.
var array = new[] {(string)null, (string)null};

// Then for each item in the array, assign it a value
// (replacing what was already there anyway)
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    array[i] = "some string";
}
```

And at the end we end up with an array that looks like `["some string", "some string"]`. Again, there is no "connection" with the fields. This issue has naught to do with reference types or not (and strings are *also* reference types).

The best (and usually correct) way is honestly to do it a different way. Although one could wrap field access/setters and there is always reflection.. If dynamic names are truly required then a Dictionary or similar should probably be used instead

---

Here is a method using a proxies to wrap the assignment operations. This example uses Actions and ["Statement Lambda" syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
var setters = new Dictionary<string, Action<Program, string>>() {
    { "name", (p, value) => p.name = value },
    { "id", (p, value) => p.id = value },
};

// For each field setter, assign a value (could use the name as a look-up)
foreach (var setter in setters.Values) {
    setter(this, "some string");
}
```

This works because `setter(..)` invokes the action defined earlier that actually assigns to the appropriate member. Using such a look-up/proxy (using actions, functions, or more complex types) is a valid approach for some situations, but should probably be avoided when not needed.

---

This *can* also be done with [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var t = this.GetType();
var fieldNames = new [] { "name", "id" };
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
foreach (var name in fieldNames) {
   var fieldInfo = t.GetField(name, bindingFlags);
   fieldInfo.SetValue(this, "some string");
}
```

Reflection should generally be a "method of last resort". It loses static typing information, pushes off many errors until run-time, and carries a performance penalty (that, granted, likely doesn't matter). There are some really nifty things that can be done (especially when Expressions and Annotations are also used) .. but reflection is magic best left until it's really needed.

Comment: ok that's fine. I can see why it doesn't works. However I want to know a way that works. Do you know that?

Comment: I understood your explanation. I can see now why it doesn't works. But I would like to know an explanation that solves the above problem of initializing fields with the corressponding values of array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and clear info. Which one would you suggest? Reflection or using proxy wrapping? Is reflection slow? I only have 20 fields though.

Comment: I would set them directly, but if I *had* to pick one approach it would be the explicit proxy/mapping.

Answer (score 2):

See if this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
public class Program
{
    private string name;
    private string id;
    private Dictionary<string, int> mapper = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private String[] array= null;
    public Program()
    {
        mapper.Add("name", 1);
        mapper.Add("id", 2);
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return array[mapper["name"]]; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return array[mapper["id"]]; }
    }

    private void Func()
    {
        array = new[] { name, id };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = "some string";
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Func();
        Console.WriteLine(p.name); // prints null
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a mapper is a overhead here, but thats best i can think of.